# Could not find sshkit-1.1.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I'm attempting to deploy my Rails 4 application using Capistrano v3 but I'm running into an issue. When I run `cap production deploy` it get `Could not find sshkit-1.1.0 in any of the sources`:

```
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
 INFO Uploading /tmp/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [252f9509] Running chmod +x /tmp/git-ssh.sh on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [252f9509] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production chmod +x /tmp/git-ssh.sh )
 INFO [252f9509] Finished in 0.376 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [ec2838c5] Running git ls-remote git@github.com:kyledecot/skateboxes.git on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [ec2838c5] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/git-ssh.sh git ls-remote git@github.com:kyledecot/skateboxes.git )
DEBUG [ec2838c5] Finished in 1.531 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [ec2838c5]    467c02d70e842257d72f3625b39fd48b483cf1b9    HEAD
DEBUG [ec2838c5]    467c02d70e842257d72f3625b39fd48b483cf1b9    refs/heads/master
DEBUG [ec2838c5] Finished in 1.531 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [f70985e2] Running mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/shared /var/www/skateboxes/releases on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [f70985e2] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/shared /var/www/skateboxes/releases )
 INFO [f70985e2] Finished in 1.135 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [2f76964e] Running mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/shared/public/assets on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [2f76964e] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/shared/public/assets )
 INFO [2f76964e] Finished in 0.963 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [5cf623c4] Running mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [5cf623c4] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config )
 INFO [5cf623c4] Finished in 1.057 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [80f4f9cd] Running [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/database.yml ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [80f4f9cd] Command: [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [80f4f9cd] Finished in 0.930 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [3f02b840] Running [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/unicorn.rb ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [3f02b840] Command: [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/unicorn.rb ]
DEBUG [3f02b840] Finished in 0.569 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [3228b59c] Running [ -d /usr/local/rvm ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [3228b59c] Command: [ -d /usr/local/rvm ]
DEBUG [3228b59c] Finished in 1.019 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [528485fa] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm wrapper 2.0@skateboxes skateboxes bundle gem rake ruby on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [528485fa] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm wrapper 2.0@skateboxes skateboxes bundle gem rake ruby )
DEBUG [528485fa]    Saving wrappers to '/usr/local/rvm/bin'.
DEBUG [528485fa]    .
DEBUG [528485fa]    .
DEBUG [528485fa]    .
DEBUG [528485fa]
 INFO [528485fa] Finished in 1.592 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [e2eb2c08] Running [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/repo/HEAD ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [e2eb2c08] Command: [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG [e2eb2c08] Finished in 1.071 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO The repository mirror is at /var/www/skateboxes/repo
DEBUG [956fc93b] Running if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [956fc93b] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [956fc93b] Finished in 1.072 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [570438ec] Running git remote update on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [570438ec] Command: cd /var/www/skateboxes/repo && ( RAILS_ENV=production git remote update )
DEBUG [570438ec]    Fetching origin
 INFO [570438ec] Finished in 1.095 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [9ebdee11] Running if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [9ebdee11] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [9ebdee11] Finished in 0.786 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [eb7b5824] Running mkdir -p /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124 on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [eb7b5824] Command: cd /var/www/skateboxes/repo && ( RAILS_ENV=production GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/git-ssh.sh mkdir -p /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124 )
 INFO [eb7b5824] Finished in 0.522 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [8c1c053b] Running git archive master | tar -x -C /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124 on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [8c1c053b] Command: cd /var/www/skateboxes/repo && ( RAILS_ENV=production GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/git-ssh.sh git archive master | tar -x -C /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124 )
 INFO [8c1c053b] Finished in 0.509 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [db3dadbc] Running mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [db3dadbc] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config )
 INFO [db3dadbc] Finished in 1.021 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [0df77725] Running [ -L /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/database.yml ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [0df77725] Command: [ -L /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [0df77725] Finished in 0.510 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [1941236c] Running [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/database.yml ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [1941236c] Command: [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [1941236c] Finished in 0.496 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 INFO [8afe039a] Running ln -s /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/database.yml /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/database.yml on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [8afe039a] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production ln -s /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/database.yml /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/database.yml )
 INFO [8afe039a] Finished in 0.525 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [eccf0bc2] Running [ -L /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/unicorn.rb ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [eccf0bc2] Command: [ -L /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/unicorn.rb ]
DEBUG [eccf0bc2] Finished in 0.409 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [f25ac179] Running [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/unicorn.rb ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [f25ac179] Command: [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/unicorn.rb ]
DEBUG [f25ac179] Finished in 0.409 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 INFO [4035f6bb] Running ln -s /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/unicorn.rb /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/unicorn.rb on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [4035f6bb] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production ln -s /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/unicorn.rb /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/config/unicorn.rb )
 INFO [4035f6bb] Finished in 0.560 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [dd6f50c6] Running mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/public on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [dd6f50c6] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/public )
 INFO [dd6f50c6] Finished in 1.012 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [4ea6454f] Running [ -L /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/public/assets ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [4ea6454f] Command: [ -L /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/public/assets ]
DEBUG [4ea6454f] Finished in 0.428 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [2e88169b] Running [ -d /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/public/assets ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [2e88169b] Command: [ -d /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/public/assets ]
DEBUG [2e88169b] Finished in 0.278 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 INFO [a9c3610d] Running ln -s /var/www/skateboxes/shared/public/assets /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/public/assets on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [a9c3610d] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production ln -s /var/www/skateboxes/shared/public/assets /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/public/assets )
 INFO [a9c3610d] Finished in 0.481 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [24864ae2] Running if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124'" 1>&2; false; fi on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [24864ae2] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [24864ae2] Finished in 0.919 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [c4aac20e] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/skateboxes_bundle --gemfile /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/Gemfile --path /var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --binstubs /var/www/skateboxes/shared/bin --without development test on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [c4aac20e] Command: cd /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124 && ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/rvm/bin/skateboxes_bundle --gemfile /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124/Gemfile --path /var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --binstubs /var/www/skateboxes/shared/bin --without development test )
 INFO [c4aac20e] Finished in 2.149 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [bad73b81] Running if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124'" 1>&2; false; fi on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [bad73b81] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [bad73b81] Finished in 0.957 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [ecf4921b] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/skateboxes_rake assets:precompile on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [ecf4921b] Command: cd /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131023013124 && ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/rvm/bin/skateboxes_rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [ecf4921b]    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find sshkit-1.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.3.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:74:in `setup'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.3.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:103:in `check'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.3.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:109:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.3.4/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.5/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `call'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.5/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.5/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.5/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
DEBUG [ecf4921b]        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
cap aborted!
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:125:in `block (4 levels) in _execute'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:149:in `block in _execute'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `tap'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `_execute'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `execute'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/capistrano-rails-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:61:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:89:in `with'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/capistrano-rails-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:60:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:81:in `within'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/capistrano-rails-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:59:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `instance_exec'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `run'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
```

*Capfile*

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

**deploy.rb**

```
...
set :rvm_ruby_version, "2.0@skateboxes"
...
```

**Update #1**

It seems like the line that is failing is attempting to use the 2.0@global gemset even though I have set `rvm_ruby_version` in my deploy.rb

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find sshkit-1.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similiar problem and had to define a new bundle and map some commands. So this is definetely not a perfect solution, but it worked for us:

Something like this:

```
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake]  = "~/.rvm/bin/new_bundle exec rake"
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rails] = "~/.rvm/bin/new_bundle exec rails"
SSHKit.config.command_map[:ruby_executable_hooks] = "~/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks"
```